# Can I buy Daedra hearts from anywhere?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find Daedra hearts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36656/where-can-i-find-daedra-hearts)

Is there any shops in Skyrim where I can buy daedra hearts?

Answer (score 0):

[Enthir](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enthir), a shady purveyor of alchemy ingredients in the college of winterhold, will restock 2 daedra hearts every 2 game days.

Comment: What is his name?

Comment: Oh...fail sry lol...